# Why is my code ignoring the while?

Tags: c, while-loop

So here is the code, it ignores the while and I don't know why, it is supposed to start with the while as soon as you enter a value for the first printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
     int main()
     {
        str WhoOwes,Fabri,Alen,Amilcar,Maxi,Lolo;
        int RandomInt=0,Deudores;

        printf("How many people owes?:");
        scanf("&d",&Deudores);
        while(RandomInt <= Deudores);
         {
         printf("who owes?:");
         scanf("&c",&WhoOwes);
         if(scanf("%c",&WhoOwes)==Fabri)
            {
                Fabri= Fabri+1;
                printf("Fabri debe $",Fabri*4);
            }
         }
        return 0;
     }
```

Thanks!H

Comment: You have a `;` after, remove it and it will work.

Comment: Oh my...how didn't I see it? Thanks! this happens when I start programming without my glasses haha EDIT: Tried but still doesn't work :/

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code? It looks kinda... weird what with the str type being used and the wrong printf format-string and all.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
while(RandomInt <= Deudores);
```

To (remove the semicolon):

```
while(RandomInt <= Deudores)
```

Also, the delimiter you use in `scanf` should be `%d` not `&d`.

Further more, what type is `str`?

You are using `scanf` delimiter`%d` which is for an `int` to store into a `str` type which, I assume is some sort of a `struct`. If it is, this is not the way to do that. You have to store information into each part of the `struct` separately. Or change the type `str` to an `int`. This could be the reason why your while loop doesn't happen because you are trying to compare an `int` to a `str`:

```
while(RandomInt <= Deudores);  // Deudores is a str
```

Then you are reading information twice by calling `scanf()` twice but you are only comparing what you get the second time. Also, the first time you read it you use the `&c` delimiter which is invalid. It should be `%c`. Further more, you create the `str Fabri` variable above with an invalid type `str` and also you don't give it a value anywhere in your code so you cannot do the comparison in the `if` statement:

```
scanf("&c",&WhoOwes);
if(scanf("%c",&WhoOwes)==Fabri)
```

Since you are using the character delimiter `%c`, you should declare `WhoOwes` and `Fabri` as `char` types to have consistent logic although it isn't technically required since `int` and `char` store interchangeable information. You must also initialize the `Fabri` variable to some `char` value.

However, in the end of your code you have the statement:

```
printf("Fabri debe $",Fabri*4);
```

This will not work because you are missing a delimiter where to print the `Fabri*4` value. 
Change that line to:

```
printf("Fabri debe %d$",Fabri*4); // add the %d delimiter to print the actual value
```

Since you are using `Fabri` in a calculation, you should then probably declare all your variables as `int` and read them using the `%d` delimiter, not `%c`.

Your program should look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
    int WhoOwes, Fabri, Alen, Amilcar, Maxi, Lolo; // these are int types  not str types
    int RandomInt = 0, Deudores;

    Fabri = 5; // initialize Fabri to some value that can be used for comparisons

    printf("How many people owes?:");
    scanf("%d",&Deudores);
    while(RandomInt <= Deudores);
     {
     printf("who owes?:");
     scanf("%d",&WhoOwes);  // use 
     if(WhoOwes == Fabri)  // use what you scanned the first time to compare to Fabri
        {
            Fabri= Fabri+1;
            printf("Fabri debe %d$",Fabri*4); // add the int delimiter %d to actually print the money amount
        }
     }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: So I have to give 'Fabri' a value?